# Display rank according to a criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Good afternoon,

I would like to display a rank of values meeting a specific criteria. On the example below, I want to display a rank for values that meet the criteria "X". I have managed to display the first value easily with a `MINIFS()` formula (image attached).

I cannot manage to display others values, that is to say the smallest value but superior to the one I just found. Could you please help?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: So you want to show `2`,`5`,`9`,`12` in different cells?

Comment: Yes @ScottCraner! I guess I have to use the small() formula but I am not sure how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use AGGREGATE:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,7,$I$12:$I$23/($H$12:$H$23="X"),ROW(1:1))
```

Or the SMALL() formula as an array formula:

```
=SMALL(IF($H$12:$H$23="X",$I$12:$I$23),ROW(1:1))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Both these formulas are meant to be dragged/copied down.  If one wants to drag/copy over then change `ROW(1:1)` to `COLUMN(A:A)`

Comment: Wow, you're good! It worked thank you. Though, I don't understand how `Aggregate` works... Could you please explain me a bit so I can use in later? I'm confused with the `I12:I23/(H12:H23="X"),ROW(1:1))` part. Thanks!

Comment: Aggregate works on ignoring errors(The 7 in the second criterion).  When ever the denominator is false it will cause an error that gets ignored.  so only when it is true does the aggregate consider the number.  It then returns the rank depicted by the ROW(1:1) which changes as the formula is dragged down.